# angularjs form with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Speaks Blz guys ?!

Am new to angularjs and I am Brazilian, excuse me by the English, was translated into google.

I'm developing a form but can not make abstraction of the ng-model. Follow the instructions below for better understanding.

<---JS---->

```
/* CONFIGURAÇÃO DO FORM */
            $scope.cfgForm = {
                item: {
                    field: ["nome", "idade", "funcao"],
                    headers: ["Nome", "Idade", "Função"],
                    icon: ["person", "date_range", "business_center"]
                }
            };
            /* DADOS */
            $scope.clientes = [
                {nome: "Pablo Mendoça", idade: 25, funcao: "Estagiário"},
                {nome: "Ricardo Leite", idade: 41, funcao: "Diretor"},
                {nome: "Francisco Motta", idade: 35, funcao: "Gerente de Contas"}
            ];

            /* FUNÇÕES */
            /* ADICIONAR CLIENTE */
            $scope.addCliente = function(cliente){
                console.log(cliente);
            };
```

<--------- HTML ----------->

```
<div>
                            <!--{{cfgForm.item.field[k]}}-->
                            <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" ng-repeat="(k,field) in cfgForm.item.field">
                                <label>{{cfgForm.item.headers[k]}}</label>
                                <md-icon><i class="material-icons" >{{cfgForm.item.icon[k]}}</i></md-icon>
                                <input ng-model="cliente.field" type="text">
                                <!--{{cliente.k}}-->
                            </md-input-container>
                            <!--Botões de ação do Card-->
                            {{cliente}}
                            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="addCliente(cliente)">
                                    <i class="material-icons" >add_box</i>
                                    <md-tooltip  md-direction="left">
                                        Adicionar
                                    </md-tooltip>
                                </md-button>
                            </md-card-actions>
                        </div>
                    </md-card-content>
```

Well, what happens is that when I put the button to add the ng-repeat it abstracts the data and shows on the island, however it can not be repeated, ie the button should stay out of the ng-repeat. As I am mostranto above.

I would like help. I do not know if it is acceptable this type of question here but if not, ever apologize!

Comment: If you're having trouble on the English site, you can always try [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "track by $index" to your ng-repeat:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" ng-repeat="(k,field) in cfgForm.item.field track by $index">
```